# Is it true that kernel of an endomorphism $f$ is not null if $0$ is eigenvalue of $f$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

$f$ is an endomorphism of the vector space $V$. Is it true that if $0$ is an eigenvalue of $f$ then $\ker(f)$ contains at least a non-null vector?

**My attempt**: from the definition of eigenvector,

$f(v) = \lambda v$

in this case, $\lambda = 0$, then $f(v) = 0$. We know, for this reason, that v is an eigenvector of $f$ and we also know that an eigenvector, by definition, cannot be null. So $\dim(\ker(f)) \neq 0$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning and answer are correct.